# How to Prove or disprove : Let I be an ideal of R and R/I be a integral domain then R is an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Prove or disprove : Let I be an ideal of R and R/I be a integral domain then R is an integral domain.

I am confused this is true or not. My approach is if I assume that R is not a integral domain then there exist some a,b$\in$ R-I such that ab=0 then (a+I)(b+I)=ab+I=I,which contradicts the fact that R/I is a integral domain. But I am not sure if my proof is right or wrong. It will be enough if you give me some hint and if there is a better solution I will appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get satisfaction out of telling people their questions on stackexchange are obvious? @Randall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in assuming that if $R$ is not an integral domain then you must be able to find a pair of zero divisors, neither element living in $I$.  You wrote $a, b \in R-I$, but there is no guarantee of that.  Instead, all you can say is that $a, b \in R$ are both non-zero yet $ab =0$.  This does *not* yield a contradiction once you carry out your coset multiplications.

Instead, the claim is false.  You can quotient out $\{0,2\}$ from the ring $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (not an integral domain) and get (something isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is a field.

Comment: Yes I get that I was actually confused and didn't find any example so I was trying to prove that. What you have pointed out is right there is no guarantee of existence of such a and b. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  I have a habit of searching for super-small counterexamples whenever I'm stumped.  It has helped me greatly.